# How to indent and hanging indent

Tags: indentation

I am having trouble with indenting. I would like a non-indented paragraph to be followed by an indented multi-line example. That example should have a hanging indent. I've tried using the `hanging` package, with no success. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,twoside,final]{book}

\begin{document}

\noindent Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. \\

{\textbf{Example}}: Suppose this is an example. I would like the example to be indented (yay, it is!), and I would like the text on the next line of the example to line up with the letter ``S" in ``Suppose" at the beginning of the first sentence in the example. \\

\noindent Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `description` list:

```
\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries Example:}]
  \item [Example:] Suppose this is an example. I would like ... 
\end{description}
```

[image]

If you also want to indent the entire *Example* block you can use `labelindent`. For instance, with

```
\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries Example:},labelindent=2.0em]
  \item [Example:] Suppose this is an example. I would like ... 
\end{description}
```

you get:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,twoside,final]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\noindent Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. 

\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries Example:}]
  \item [Example:] Suppose this is an example. I would like the example to be indented (yay, it is!), and I would like the text on the next line of the example to line up with the letter ``S" in ``Suppose" at the beginning of the first sentence in the example. 
\end{description}

\noindent Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only issue: "Example" is not indented. How can this be fixed?

Comment: You can use `labelindent=2.0em`, for example.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Could you please include that in the code?

Comment: Wonderful, thank you again!

Comment: Sir --Kindly let me know how to indent the first line only in front of label"example" so that " Suppose " is shifted right by say 1cm--Thanks

Comment: @jsbibra: I think using `labelsep=\dimexpr1cm+1ex\relax, itemindent=1cm` should be pretty close to what you want.  However, I suggest you post a new question since this required a `1ex` tweak.  Also, no need for formalities - Happy to help if I can.

Answer (score 2):

You should never need `\indent` or `\noindent` in a document, the layout of paragraphs should be a document wide setting, not something to secify each time. Also never end a paragraph with `\\` (LaTeX warns about that in the log)

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,twoside,final]{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newenvironment{example}
               {%
\sbox0{\textbf{example}: }%
\list{}{\labelwidth\wd0 \leftmargin\wd0 \labelsep 0pt }
             \item[\usebox0]}
               {\endlist}

\begin{document}

Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph.%no! \\

\begin{example}
Suppose this is an example. I would like the example to be indented (yay, it is!), and I would like the text on the next line of the example to line up with the letter ``S'' in ``Suppose'' at the beginning of the first sentence in the example.%no!! \\
\end{example}

Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir --Kindly let me know how to indent the first line only in front of label"example" so that " Suppose " is shifted right by say 1cm--Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility uses the `linegoal` package, which measures the remaining space on the line at its point of insertion:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,twoside,final]{book}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}

\noindent Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. \\

\textbf{Example}: \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{Suppose this is an example. I would like the example to be indented (yay, it is!), and I would like the text on the next line of the example to line up with the letter ``S" in ``Suppose" at the beginning of the first sentence in the example. \\h. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. \\}

\noindent Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph. Words are here, and they form a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir --Kindly let me know how to indent the first line only in front of label"example" so that " Suppose " is shifted right by say 1cm--Thanks