# Strange indent for some lines

Tags: indentation, overleaf

I would like to have, from the second line a different indentation only for some lines. For now I have fixed manually entering when serving hspace() but it is not a smart solution... There is a way? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

EDIT, my code:

```
 \section*{WHAT I HAVE}
    Una rete è una interconnessione di dispositivi in grado di    scambiarsi informazioni. Si indica con hosts i sistemi terminali, cioè i sistemi che risiedono alla periferia della rete e che usano la rete per scopi applicativi, trasmissione di contenuti, streaming di file, ... Per far comunicare gli hosts tra di loro occorrono le tecnologie di comunicazione che prendono il nome di link o collegamenti. \medskip \\ 
    \textbf{Esempio 1}. Si consideri l'invio di un file di 1 Mbit su    un datalink di lunghezza di 4800 km. Calcolare il ritardo di propagazione
\begin{center}
    $r_{pr} = \frac{\displaystyle d[m]}{\displaystyle s[m/sec]} = \frac{\displaystyle 4800 \cdot 10^3 \ m}{\displaystyle 3\cdot10^8 \ m/sec} = 0.016[sec] $
\end{center}
Sia la velocità di trasmissione pari a 64 kbps, calcolare il ritardo di trasmissione
\begin{center}
    $r_{tr} = \frac{\displaystyle L [bits]}{\displaystyle R[bps]} = \frac{\displaystyle 10^6 \ bits}{\displaystyle 64 \cdot 10^3 \ bps} = 15.625 [sec]$
\end{center}
\textbf{Esempio 2.} Ci sono 10 auto in carovana e due caselli. Le automobili viaggiano alla velocità di 100 km/h. Il casello fa transitare un'auto ogni 12 secondi. Quanto tempo occorre affinché le 10 auto in carovana si trovino di fronte al secondo casello? \textit{Ipotesi semplificativa}: la prima auto che arriva al casello attende le altre nove
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.41\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    $r_{tr} = 12 \cdot 10 = 120 \ sec$
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.46\textwidth}
     \textit{tempo richiesto al casello per trasmettere l'intera carovana}
\end{minipage}
\medskip \\ 
\begin{minipage}{.41\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    $r_{pr} = \frac{\displaystyle 100 \ km}{\displaystyle (100 \ km/h)} = 1 \ h$
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.46\textwidth}
     \textit{tempo richiesto a un'auto per viaggiare dall'uscita di un casello fino al casello successivo}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You have given no information about your input so hard to tell you what to change but indenting after the **Example 2** label could easily be set up as a `description` list with the margin set using `enumitem`

Comment: I'm sorry, i put my code, thanks in advance

Comment: Related: [How to indent and hanging indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509106)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Carlisle has already suggested in a comment, you may be well served by employing a `description` environment. (I wouldn't apply as much hanging indentation as you claim you want to do.) Oh, and do also use the machinery of the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units and the associated quantities.

And, for crying out loud, *who* taught you to write something as messed up as

```
\begin{center}
    $r_{pr} = \frac{\displaystyle d[m]}{\displaystyle s[m/sec]} 
    = \frac{\displaystyle 4800 \cdot 10^3 \ m}{\displaystyle 3\cdot10^8 \ m/sec} 
    = 0.016[sec] $
\end{center}
```

Do please familiarize yourself with the tools available to LaTeX users for typesetting displayed math material. I hope you'll agree that writing

```
\[
   r_{pr} = \frac{d[m]}{s[m/sec]} 
     = \frac{4800 \cdot 10^3 \, m}{3\cdot10^8 \, m/sec} 
     = 0.016[sec]
\]
```

is much to be preferred. (I trust you have figured out by now that `\[` and `\]` serve to initiate and terminate a single-line unnumbered display-math group.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Una rete è una interconnessione di dispositivi in grado di  scambiarsi informazioni. Si indica con hosts i sistemi terminali, cioè i sistemi che risiedono alla periferia della rete e che usano la rete per scopi applicativi, trasmissione di contenuti, streaming di file, \dots{} Per far comunicare gli hosts tra di loro occorrono le tecnologie di comunicazione che prendono il nome di link o collegamenti.
    
\begin{description} 
\item[Esempio 1.] 
Si consideri l'invio di un file di 1 Mbit su un datalink di lunghezza di 4800 km. Calcolare il ritardo di propagazione
\[
r_{pr} = \frac{d[\si{\meter}]}{s[\si{\meter\per\second}]} 
= \frac{\qty{4800e3}{\meter}}{\qty{3e8}{\meter\per\second}} = 0.016[\si{\second}] 
\]
Sia la velocità di trasmissione pari a 64 kbps, calcolare il ritardo di trasmissione
\[r_{tr} = \frac{L [bits]}{R[bps]} = \frac{10^6 \ bits}{64 \cdot 10^3 \ bps} = 15.625 [sec]
\]

\item[Esempio 2.] 
Ci sono 10 auto in carovana e due caselli. Le automobili viaggiano alla velocità di 100 km/h. Il casello fa transitare un'auto ogni 12 secondi. Quanto tempo occorre affinché le 10 auto in carovana si trovino di fronte al secondo casello? \textit{Ipotesi semplificativa}: la prima auto che arriva al casello attende le altre nove
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.41\textwidth}
\centering
$r_{tr} = 12 \cdot 10 = \qty{120}{\second}$
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.46\textwidth}
\textit{tempo richiesto al casello per trasmettere l'intera carovana}
\end{minipage}\\[2ex]
\begin{minipage}{.41\textwidth}
\centering
$r_{pr} = \dfrac{\qty{100}{\kilo\meter}}{(\qty{100}{\kilo\meter\per\hour})} = \qty{1}{\hour}$
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.46\textwidth}
\textit{tempo richiesto a un'auto per viaggiare dall'uscita di un casello fino al casello successivo}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```