# How can I "indent a full row" in a table

Tags: tables, math-mode, indentation, bullets

I don't even know how to ask this.  I've been using longtable in order to create invisible tables so that I can do the following explanation of formula parameters(if there's a better way of doing this I'd gladly hear it):

[image: I've been using longtable to make the list of descriptions of the formulae parameters]

But I can't figure out how to achieve the following:

[image: The top row is literally "indented"]

How can I indent in a way that it looks like a sub-bullet point but without the bullet points of course.  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is commonly called "hanging indentation". https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509106/how-to-indent-and-hanging-indent for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indent text like so, using `itemize` environment with a help of [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package that allows to specify margin width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[nosep, left=11ex]
\item[$\sigma_\mathrm{FlimN}$] fatigue strength under pulsating stress, expressed by the nominal stress (values for different thermoplastics as a function of the required number of load cycles; see   Figure 3 and Table 5)
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item[$S_\mathrm{Fmin}$] required minimum safety factor (generally $S_\mathrm{Fmin }=2.0$ for continuous operation, where a setting of $N_\mathrm{L}=10^8$ load cycles is required and $S_\mathrm{Fmin}=1.6$ in the case of intermittent operation with $N_\mathrm{L}$ load cycles)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.  First of all thanks for your help, I think that is exactly what I wanted :).  I'm curious what part of your code hides the bullet points.  Is it the enumitem package or the [nosep] option?

Comment: Actually, it's the default behavior of `\item`  command. If you pass something as an optional argument `\item[something]`, you'll get that instead of a bullet.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, have a nice day :)